# Proof of Newton–Cotes quadrature rules, I guess?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, quadrature

I've been searching for the proof of this formula, I think the main problem is that the book doesn't really give it a name, therefore it's hard to search it up even online. I read the topics suggested by the site while I was asking this question but coulnd't find this exact formula.

Can anyone help me find the proof or suggest some resources where to find it?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

(Sorry for the italian)

Comment: **Estimate of the quadrature error** Let ... Under these hypothesis of regularity of the function, the following result holds (the proof of which is found in the example at ...) Let .. Then ...

Comment: Without knowledge of $\gamma_n$ and/or more context, it is impossible to know.

Comment: Apparently the theorem in question is for some specific class of quadrature rules because [it's not true for all quadrature rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1770264). If you knew the theorem were true for a given quadrature rule, as it is for Gaussian-type rules, it would be a snap to find $k$ and $\gamma_n$. I have never seen a readable proof that the theorem is valid for Simpson's $3/8$ rule athough or course it is.